# Fabricjs scale paths in a path-group from svg

Tags: javascript, svg, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I've got two SVGs in the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zxkh0o2t/) but only one is displaying due the second being very large.

Is there a need to scale the group paths individually?

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

// svgs
svg1 = document.getElementById('svg1').innerHTML;
svg2 = document.getElementById('svg2').innerHTML;
     
var zoomScale = 0.8;
     
function loadSVG(svg, top) {
  fabric.loadSVGFromString(svg, function(objects, options) {
    var obj = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);

    obj.fill = 'rgb(0,0,0)';
    obj.top = top;
    obj.left = 10;
    obj.width = canvas.width / 2;
    obj.height = canvas.height / 2;
    obj.strokeWidth = 1;
    obj.stroke = 'green';

    obj.scaleX = zoomScale;
    obj.scaleY = zoomScale;

    console.log('obj', obj)

    canvas.add(obj);
    
    obj.setCoords();

    canvas.setActiveObject(obj);
  });
}

// Works
loadSVG(svg1, 10);

// Not Works
loadSVG(svg2, 300)
```

Fabricjs version: 1.7.9
http://jsfiddle.net/zxkh0o2t/

```
{
    "type": "path-group",
    "originX": "left",
    "originY": "top",
    "left": 10,
    "top": 300,
    "width": 300,
    "height": 300,
    "fill": "rgb(0,0,0)",
    "stroke": "green",
    "strokeWidth": 1,
    "strokeDashArray": null,
    "strokeLineCap": "butt",
    "strokeLineJoin": "miter",
    "strokeMiterLimit": 10,
    "scaleX": 0.8,
    "scaleY": 0.8,
    "angle": 0,
    "flipX": false,
    "flipY": false,
    "opacity": 1,
    "shadow": null,
    "visible": true,
    "clipTo": null,
    "backgroundColor": "",
    "fillRule": "nonzero",
    "globalCompositeOperation": "source-over",
    "transformMatrix": null,
    "skewX": 0,
    "skewY": 0,
    "paths": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "originX": "left",
            "originY": "top",
            "left": 44.883,
            "top": 4056.7746,
            "width": 1172.3,
            "height": 4060.82,
            "fill": "rgb(0,0,0)",
            "stroke": null,
            "strokeWidth": 1,
            "strokeDashArray": null,
            "strokeLineCap": "butt",
            "strokeLineJoin": "miter",
            "strokeMiterLimit": 10,
            "scaleX": 1,
            "scaleY": 1,
            "angle": 0,
            "flipX": false,
            "flipY": false,
            "opacity": 1,
            "shadow": null,
            "visible": true,
            "clipTo": null,
            "backgroundColor": "",
            "fillRule": "nonzero",
            "globalCompositeOperation": "source-over",
            "transformMatrix": null,
            "skewX": 0,
            "skewY": 0,
            "pathOffset": {
                "x": 631.0309500000001,
                "y": 6087.1831
            },
            "path": [
                [
                    "m",
                    44.883,
                    6088.0787
                ],
                [
                    "c",
                    0,
                    867.8099,
                    471.49754,
                    1624.1118,
                    1172.2959,
                    2029.5129
                ],
                [
                    "V",
                    4056.7746
                ],
                [
                    "C",
                    516.40101,
                    4462.1552,
                    44.883,
                    5220.3197,
                    44.883,
                    6088.0787
                ],
                [
                    "z"
                ]
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "path",
            "originX": "left",
            "originY": "top",
            "left": 1275.8091,
            "top": 274.8115623679888,
            "width": 7385.29,
            "height": 7842.68,
            "fill": "rgb(0,0,0)",
            "stroke": null,
            "strokeWidth": 1,
            "strokeDashArray": null,
            "strokeLineCap": "butt",
            "strokeLineJoin": "miter",
            "strokeMiterLimit": 10,
            "scaleX": 1,
            "scaleY": 1,
            "angle": 0,
            "flipX": false,
            "flipY": false,
            "opacity": 1,
            "shadow": null,
            "visible": true,
            "clipTo": null,
            "backgroundColor": "",
            "fillRule": "nonzero",
            "globalCompositeOperation": "source-over",
            "transformMatrix": null,
            "skewX": 0,
            "skewY": 0,
            "pathOffset": {
                "x": 4968.454199999998,
                "y": 4196.150381183995
            },
            "path": [
                [
                    "M",
                    7473.4,
                    970.2098
                ],
                [
                    "C",
                    5740.9526,
                    43.0377,
                    4195.9046,
                    42.9866,
                    2463.5594,
                    970.2098
                ],
                [
                    "C",
                    1873.3177,
                    1286.0869,
                    1275.8091,
                    2000.3953,
                    1275.8091,
                    2754.4453
                ],
                [
                    "v",
                    5363.0439
                ],
                [
                    "h",
                    644.7423
                ],
                [
                    "V",
                    2754.4453
                ],
                [
                    "c",
                    0,
                    -515.7323,
                    620.4344,
                    -1172.8076,
                    1154.18,
                    -1393.8796
                ],
                [
                    "c",
                    1433.6421,
                    -593.8241,
                    2354.0081,
                    -593.8241,
                    3787.4454,
                    0
                ],
                [
                    "c",
                    533.7456,
                    221.0873,
                    1154.1801,
                    878.1473,
                    1154.1801,
                    1393.8796
                ],
                [
                    "v",
                    5363.0439
                ],
                [
                    "h",
                    644.7424
                ],
                [
                    "V",
                    2754.4453
                ],
                [
                    "c",
                    0,
                    -754.1014,
                    -597.5085,
                    -1468.3893,
                    -1187.7504,
                    -1784.2355
                ],
                [
                    "z"
                ]
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "path",
            "originX": "left",
            "originY": "top",
            "left": 8719.4888,
            "top": 4056.8769,
            "width": 1172.3,
            "height": 4060.82,
            "fill": "rgb(0,0,0)",
            "stroke": null,
            "strokeWidth": 1,
            "strokeDashArray": null,
            "strokeLineCap": "butt",
            "strokeLineJoin": "miter",
            "strokeMiterLimit": 10,
            "scaleX": 1,
            "scaleY": 1,
            "angle": 0,
            "flipX": false,
            "flipY": false,
            "opacity": 1,
            "shadow": null,
            "visible": true,
            "clipTo": null,
            "backgroundColor": "",
            "fillRule": "nonzero",
            "globalCompositeOperation": "source-over",
            "transformMatrix": null,
            "skewX": 0,
            "skewY": 0,
            "pathOffset": {
                "x": 9305.6368,
                "y": 6087.285400000001
            },
            "path": [
                [
                    "m",
                    8719.4888,
                    4056.8769
                ],
                [
                    "v",
                    4060.817
                ],
                [
                    "c",
                    700.7781,
                    -405.3703,
                    1172.296,
                    -1161.6517,
                    1172.296,
                    -2029.513
                ],
                [
                    "c",
                    0,
                    -867.7587,
                    -471.4821,
                    -1625.9541,
                    -1172.296,
                    -2031.304
                ],
                [
                    "z"
                ]
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "path",
            "originX": "left",
            "originY": "top",
            "left": 1973.8389,
            "top": 3712.2195,
            "width": 865.6,
            "height": 4750.46,
            "fill": "rgb(0,0,0)",
            "stroke": null,
            "strokeWidth": 1,
            "strokeDashArray": null,
            "strokeLineCap": "butt",
            "strokeLineJoin": "miter",
            "strokeMiterLimit": 10,
            "scaleX": 1,
            "scaleY": 1,
            "angle": 0,
            "flipX": false,
            "flipY": false,
            "opacity": 1,
            "shadow": null,
            "visible": true,
            "clipTo": null,
            "backgroundColor": "",
            "fillRule": "nonzero",
            "globalCompositeOperation": "source-over",
            "transformMatrix": null,
            "skewX": 0,
            "skewY": 0,
            "pathOffset": {
                "x": 2406.64115,
                "y": 6087.45175
            },
            "path": [
                [
                    "m",
                    2587.4009,
                    3712.2195
                ],
                [
                    "h",
                    -361.5194
                ],
                [
                    "c",
                    -139.1987,
                    0,
                    -252.0426,
                    112.8438,
                    -252.0426,
                    252.0476
                ],
                [
                    "v",
                    4246.3742
                ],
                [
                    "c",
                    0,
                    139.1987,
                    112.8388,
                    252.0427,
                    252.0426,
                    252.0427
                ],
                [
                    "h",
                    361.5194
                ],
                [
                    "c",
                    139.1984,
                    0,
                    252.0425,
                    -112.844,
                    252.0425,
                    -252.0427
                ],
                [
                    "V",
                    3964.2671
                ],
                [
                    "c",
                    0,
                    -139.2038,
                    -112.8389,
                    -252.0476,
                    -252.0425,
                    -252.0476
                ],
                [
                    "z"
                ]
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "path",
            "originX": "left",
            "originY": "top",
            "left": 7092.6749,
            "top": 3712.2195,
            "width": 865.61,
            "height": 4750.46,
            "fill": "rgb(0,0,0)",
            "stroke": null,
            "strokeWidth": 1,
            "strokeDashArray": null,
            "strokeLineCap": "butt",
            "strokeLineJoin": "miter",
            "strokeMiterLimit": 10,
            "scaleX": 1,
            "scaleY": 1,
            "angle": 0,
            "flipX": false,
            "flipY": false,
            "opacity": 1,
            "shadow": null,
            "visible": true,
            "clipTo": null,
            "backgroundColor": "",
            "fillRule": "nonzero",
            "globalCompositeOperation": "source-over",
            "transformMatrix": null,
            "skewX": 0,
            "skewY": 0,
            "pathOffset": {
                "x": 7525.4797499999995,
                "y": 6087.45175
            },
            "path": [
                [
                    "m",
                    7706.2421,
                    3712.2195
                ],
                [
                    "h",
                    -361.5245
                ],
                [
                    "c",
                    -139.1935,
                    0,
                    -252.0427,
                    112.8438,
                    -252.0427,
                    252.0476
                ],
                [
                    "v",
                    4246.3742
                ],
                [
                    "c",
                    0,
                    139.1987,
                    112.8492,
                    252.0427,
                    252.0427,
                    252.0427
                ],
                [
                    "h",
                    361.5245
                ],
                [
                    "c",
                    139.1933,
                    0,
                    252.0425,
                    -112.844,
                    252.0425,
                    -252.0427
                ],
                [
                    "V",
                    3964.2671
                ],
                [
                    "c",
                    0,
                    -139.2038,
                    -112.8492,
                    -252.0476,
                    -252.0425,
                    -252.0476
                ],
                [
                    "z"
                ]
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "path",
            "originX": "left",
            "originY": "top",
            "left": 2839.505999999994,
            "top": 4964.1642,
            "width": 4253.14,
            "height": 1760.38,
            "fill": "rgb(0,0,0)",
            "stroke": null,
            "strokeWidth": 1,
            "strokeDashArray": null,
            "strokeLineCap": "butt",
            "strokeLineJoin": "miter",
            "strokeMiterLimit": 10,
            "scaleX": 1,
            "scaleY": 1,
            "angle": 0,
            "flipX": false,
            "flipY": false,
            "opacity": 1,
            "shadow": null,
            "visible": true,
            "clipTo": null,
            "backgroundColor": "",
            "fillRule": "nonzero",
            "globalCompositeOperation": "source-over",
            "transformMatrix": null,
            "skewX": 0,
            "skewY": 0,
            "pathOffset": {
                "x": 4966.078349999998,
                "y": 5844.354350000003
            },
            "path": [
                [
                    "m",
                    2865.0202,
                    5880.8236
                ],
                [
                    "c",
                    22.1174,
                    -1.1208,
                    44.2298,
                    -0.9416,
                    66.3472,
                    0
                ],
                [
                    "c",
                    1.008,
                    23.3198,
                    18.5455,
                    124.8852,
                    22.8799,
                    489.2343
                ],
                [
                    "c",
                    0,
                    7.3589,
                    1.5251,
                    14.5798,
                    3.7254,
                    21.6212
                ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The problem is only the `height` and `width` parameters in the second SVG

You have currently in the second SVG:

```
width="100%"
height="100%"
```

Just change it to something like this:

```
width="300px"
height="300px"
```

And the second SVG will also appear.

Here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xp2nj3g1/

Comment: That works but is there a way of scaling this inside the canvas?

Comment: Isn't that what your `zoomscale` is for? In this variant of the fiddle, I have changed it from 0.8 to 0.2, and it scales the image appropriately. http://jsfiddle.net/xp2nj3g1/2/  

Perhaps you could mark the answer as correct, if it answers the original question of non-displaying SVG, and then ask another question for this new query?